# eclipse CSS file formatting

Tags: css, eclipse, formatting

I'm trying to make eclipse format css files my way...

Currently i've got sth like that:

```
.class{ 
 display: none; sth: other; 
}
```

But i would like to make it sth like that:

```
.class { display: none; sth: other; }
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only found in Preferences / Web /  Css files / Editor
that we can disable "Insert line breaks between props"

Other I think is somewhere in the sources of ecl. So even if you know about it -- you could fix it by implementing your own plugin to ecl.

Comment: I tried that... It doesn't work like i wanted :) And i never wrote any plugin for ecl so that's not the solution too.