# Preserve line-break in Eclipse CSS formatter

Tags: css, eclipse

In the Eclipse (3.8) CSS formatter, e.g.

```
.aaa,
.bbb,
.ccc,
.ddd {
    xxx
}
```

become

```
.aaa,.bbb,.ccc,.ddd {
    xxx
}
```

Is it possible to ask Eclipse to preserve the line breaks?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/11028886/1055987 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965891/1055987

Comment: Coincidence.. I was looking for this today and even with the Aptana Studio plugin there doesn't seem to be a way to make the formatting like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Preferences Java > Code Style > Formatter
```

See the "Never join lines" option on the "Line Wrapping and Comments" tab.

Answer (score -1):

In,

Window > Preferences > Web > CSS Files > Editor

unmark Insert line break between properties

in Line width set 999.